# Angular, sort by enting property as text input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I want to sort a list of comments by different properties such as rating, date,...
but not using buttons and get property as text in input.

by default the property is rating, but ng-repeat does not publish any thing.

my code is:

```
<div ng-controller="controller as Ctrl">
       <p>SortBy: <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="Ctrl.dish.sortProperty"></p>
<blockquote ng-repeat="comment in Ctrl.dish.comments | orderBy:'{{Ctrl.dish.sortProperty}}'">
                        <p>{{comment.rating}}</p>
                        <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                        <footer>{{comment.author}} ,<cite title="Source Title">{{comment.date| date:'mediumDate'}}</cite></footer>
 </blockquote>
</div>
```

and the controller as:

```
<script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 
        app.controller('controller', function() {
            var dish={
                          sortProperty:'rating',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"blablalbla",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"blablabla",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                // more comments
                               }
                           ]};
                    this.dish = dish; });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes and the interpolation `{{ }}`:

```
<blockquote ng-repeat="comment in Ctrl.dish.comments | orderBy: Ctrl.dish.sortProperty">
```

Comment: Thanks, and one more question, can put reverse condition in ng-model or somewhere in <input> tag ? like I want  rating shows from high to low and -rating show from low to high, now it is vise versa

Comment: Well, you can, but I'd suggest you to do it using or `radio button` or a `checkbox` (true/false). Do you need some help with this?

Comment: Thanks, but my task was using input text. of course you are right buttons make the work easier